# Delete from table onClickListener

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-delete

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor c= myDB.rawQuery("DELETE FROM contacts where id_ctc='"+t+"'",null);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Dial.this,TabLayout.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }         
              });
```

the application stops working   (Unfortunately, Tablayout has stopprd.)

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: why the application stops is it because of the delete query?

Comment: Why not comment it out and see? It looks like your intent is throwing an exception but i cant get more specific than that as i can't see your code. Make sure your intent construction is correct and the TabLayout class is not messing anything up.

Comment: or is it because the delete query is inside onClickListener

Comment: I comment it out and the other activity starts so there is no error in the intent

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    myDB.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, id_ctc + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(t) });
    Cursor c= myDB.rawQuery("DELETE FROM contacts where id_ctc='"+t+"'",null);
    Intent i = new Intent(Dial.this,TabLayout.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```